# Function template syntax error

Tags: c++, templates

I am new to templates. While going through one of the tutorials i found the following statement:

We have following function template:

```
template<class T1, class T2>
void PrintNumbers(const T1& t1Data, const T2& t2Data)
{}
```

Which calls the function in this way:

```
PrintNumbers<double, double>(10, 100);
```

***Which would produce the following template function:***

```
void PrintNumbers<double, double>(const double& t1Data, const T2& t2Data)
{}
```

But if i try the exact thing in my program it doesnt work and throws a lot of errors:

```
template<class T1, class T2>
void PrintNumbers<double, double>(const double& t1Data, const T2& t2Data)
{}
int main()
{
    PrintNumbers<double, double>(10, 100);   
    return 0;
}
```

But instead of the above function template if i use the following then it works:

```
template<class T1, class T2>
void PrintNumbers(const T1& t1Data, const T2& t2Data)
{}
```

Is there a problem in the way i am trying to understand this particular concept?
If so, what exactly would `void PrintNumbers<double, double>(const double& t1Data, const T2& t2Data)`  mean and how it can be used(in which scenario)?

Comment: You're trying to provide a specialization when there is no primary template present. I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I think OP was just a little confused with templates

Comment: try `template<>
void PrintNumbers<double, double>`

Answer (score 1):

Yep I think you are not understanding templates the right way. So when you have a templated function you need to have the definition like so

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
void PrintNumbers(const T1& t1Data, const T2& t2Data) {}
```

and call it like so

```
PrintNumbers(100.0, 100.0)
```

and that will resolve the above template to call a function that looks like so

```
void PrintNumbers(const double& t1Data, const double& t2Data);
```

What you are trying in the first case would be called [explicit template specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization). And you would do it like so

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
void PrintNumbers(const T1& t1Data, const T2& t2Data) {}

template <>
void PrintNumbers<double, double> (const double& t1Data, const double& t2Data) {/*Something else here */}
```

And then when you make function call (1) below that will go to the specialized function, and (2) and (3) will go to the 1st unspecialized one.

```
PrintNumbers(10.0, 10.0);     // (1)
PrintNumbers("some", "word"); // (2)
PrintNumbers(std::vector<int>(), std::vector<int>()); // (3)
```

There is also mechanisms in C++ called partial template specialization and non-type templates. I could go into the details of that but that would be enough to fill out a big blog post and then some. You should google them for more details. They are very useful and smart C++ programmers use them to make compile time deductions that are not possible in other languages.

Comment: For _double_ you explicitly declared : `template <>
void PrintNumbers(const double& t1Data, const double& t2Data) {/*Something else here */} ` . Here you mentioned the type _double_ inside the parathesis itself.   But  i see `template <>
void PrintNumbers<double,double>(const T1& t1Data, const T2& t2Data) {/*Something else here */}`  doesnt work. However it works when this function is a member function of some class. More confused as to why the difference in behaviour exists for a member function and a function(not of a class).

Comment: Thats  specialization of the `PrintNumbers` function. It needs to be there only after the general template i.e. `template <typename T1, typename T2> void PrintNumbers(const T1& t1Data, const T2& t2Data) {}` About why it works in a class. could you write the code you used so I can help?

Comment: **This works** `#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T1, class T2> void PrintNumbers(const T1& t1Data, const T2& t2Data) {}

template<> void PrintNumbers(const double& t1Data, const double& t2Data) {/*Something else here */} //This works. /but i dont want this

int main()
{
 PrintNumbers<double, double>(10, 100);    // int, int
 return 0;
}` **This doesnt ** : Instead of of `template<> void PrintNumbers(const double& t1Data, const double& t2Data) {/*Some}` in the above code, replace it with `template<> void PrintNumbers<double,double>(const T1& t1Data, const T2& t2Data) {} `

Answer (score 1):

So I think this is an issue of understanding the nuances of template syntax.

There are a few things all of which are very different from the compilers point of view:

- A template
- A template specialization
- A template instantiation

All of these things can happen for structs, for functions, for typedefs, etc.

When you write

```
template<class T1, class T2>
void PrintNumbers(const T1& t1Data, const T2& t2Data)
{}
```

that declares a template function. After this, you can use the symbol `PrintNumbers` as a function with two arguments, and it will *instantiate* the template, creating a corresponding function with two arguments.

If you want only a specific version, you could just not use templates at all

```
void PrintNumber(const double &, const double &)
{}
```

That would be okay.

When you write:

```
void PrintNumbers<double, double>(const double& t1Data, const T2& t2Data)
{}
```

this really doesn't mean anything and will be rejected by the compiler. When you put template parameters right after a declarator like that, it is expected to be a template specialization. However,

- for that you must use the keyword `template`, even if with empty parameter list like `template<> void PrintNumbers<double, double>(const double& t1Data, const T2& t2Data) {}`
- there must have been a PRIOR declaration of a template. You can only make a specialization of a template that already exists, the compiler won't just introduce a template for you. I can't tell you why, that's just how it works.

Usually, the way you should use templates is

- Declare the "full" template first, using `template< foo, bar, baz > my_function(A a, B b, ...) {}`
- Optionally, add some partial specializations, being careful not to make ambiguous partial specializations:
  `template<foo, bar>
  my_function<foo, bar, bar::baz_type>(A a, B b, ...) {}`
- Now instantiate the template as desired.

Comment: So inorder to have it work it needs the original template function and the speacialized function too.I see that it works only for member functions of a class. not for functions (without a class).